# CS50 Pset3 Music - what is sizeof(string) doing?

Tags: c, computer-science, sizeof, cs50

In pset3 of CS50, we're supposed to make sense of the notes.c file:

// Prints frequencies of and outputs WAV file with all notes in an octave

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "helpers.h"
#include "wav.h"

// Notes in an octave      
const string NOTES[] = {"C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F",
                    "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"
                   };

// Default octave 
#define OCTAVE 4

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
// Override default octave if specified at command line
int octave = OCTAVE;  
if (argc == 2)
{
    octave = atoi(argv[1]); 
    if (octave < 0 || octave > 8)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid octave\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
else if (argc > 2)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: notes [OCTAVE]\n");
    return 1;
}

// Open file for writing
song s = song_open("notes.wav");

// Add each semitone
for (int i = 0, n = sizeof(NOTES) / sizeof(string); i < n; i++)
{
    // Append octave to note
    char note[4];
    sprintf(note, "%s%i", NOTES[i], octave);

    // Calculate frequency of note
    int f = frequency(note);

    // Print note to screen
    printf("%3s: %i\n", note, f);

    // Write (eighth) note to file
    note_write(s, f, 1);
}

// Close file
song_close(s);
}
```

The part I can't make sense of is :
    for (int i = 0, n = sizeof(NOTES) / sizeof(string); i < n; i++)

For `sizeof(string)` to work, wouldn't there need to be a variable named `string` somewhere in the code? e.g. a string actually called `string`?

Not really sure what it's referring to.

Comment: Given that `NOTES` is defined as `const string NOTES[] = ...`, it gives you the clue that it's actually a type.

Comment: When dealing with CS50, it's probably best to get rid of all references to `string`, which obfuscates a fundamental C type - `char *`.  CS50's misguided attempt to simplify how C strings work is like trying to teach arithmetic without explaining what a number is.  It simply doesn't work because it prevents the fundamental understanding necessary to use C strings properly.

Comment: Beware of the `string` typedef in CS50, because what it defines isn't actually a *string*, but a pointer to a `char` (`char *`).  In C, a string is a sequence of character values including a 0-valued terminator.  Strings are stored in arrays of `char`.  Under most circumstances, expressions of type "array of `T`" are converted to "pointer to `T`", so most of the time when we're dealing with strings we're dealing with expressions of type `char *`, but a `char *` *is not a string*.  It provides a misleading picture of how string handling actually works in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *For `sizeof(string)` to work, wouldn't there need to be a variable named `string` somewhere in the code?*

Nopes, `sizeof` operator can be used on an operand of a "type", like `sizeof(int)`. Quoting the spec (*emphasis mine*)

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized **name of a type**. [....]

You can see the usage of `string` type in your code:

```
const string NOTES[] = {"C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F",
                    "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"
                   };
```

So, `NOTES` is an array of **type** `string`, `string` is a type name here.

The expression

```
 for (int i = 0, n = sizeof(NOTES) / sizeof(string); i < n; i++)
```

is a very *poor* attempt to count the members in the array, it could have been re-written as

```
 for (int i = 0, n = sizeof(NOTES) / sizeof(NOTES[0]); i < n; i++)
```

which basically divides the size of the whole array by the size of one element, producing the count of members, for sake of readability.

To add the exact source, [Check the header file `<cs50.h>`](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/develop/src/cs50.h), `string` is defined to be a *type* there.

The exact definition is:

```
 /**
 * Our own data type for string variables.
 */
typedef char *string;
```

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof` can be used on variables/expressions as well as types. Here, `string` is a type but `NOTES` is an instance of a variable (an array).

The root of the problem is caused by CS-50 `typedef char* string;`. Overall the code is a perfect example of obfuscation. Hiding pointers behind typedefs is widely recognized as terrible practice.

What the code actually says is this:

```
const char* NOTES[] = { ...
...
sizeof(NOTES) / sizeof(NOTES[0])
```

If it had been written like above, there would be no doubt of what it does: divide the size of the array with the size of each individual member, to get the number of items in the array.

I would advise to stop using the CS-50 tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I'll probably finish CS50 now that I've started it, but out of interest, can you recommend any other c courses/books in particular?